# Django auto path arrangement for static files when prepared template adding

Tags: python, regex, django

When adding a prepared  template such as bootstrap template into a django project. I change all src path which is linking local statics files  such as  javascript, css and images.I  want to automate this operations .Is there any way for doing  this ? In my opinion,using regex it will be possible.Howeever I can not until now

I put a few patterns down to be the example

```
<img src="images/slide-dark.jpg" alt="" >
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

will be like this

```
<img src="{% static 'images/slide-dark.jpg' %}">
<link href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: I started to play around with some regexes, but I think we may need more that one.  If it's really just 3 different kinds of lines ( <img...  <link.... <script... ) we can easily write 3 regexes to work.  If the regex needs to be more generic we need better rules.  The <img line removes the alt="" tag, but the <link line keeps the rel="...."   so a generic regex looks to be much more challenging.